# Is this a bug in 'date' command version 8.28/8.30?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sudo, date

When I want to display the date in format YYYY-MM-DD I use the command:

```
date +%Y%m%d
```

This worked for ages without a problem.
Now in Unbuntu 20.04LTS with the date command version 8.30, it gives an error:

```
date: multiple output formats specified
```

However, if I do:

```
sudo date +%Y%m%d
```

then it works fine again. Weird that you have to have root privileges to read the date.
But now the strange thing:

**Even if I'm root then I also need to use `sudo`**,
otherwise, I get the same error.
This seems very strange to me. Is there a special reason for this?
Or is this a bug?

Comment: Use `type date` to see if `date` is an alias, or comes from a funny directory in `$PATH`

Comment: Try quoting the parameter: `date "+%Y%m%d"`

Comment: Check for funny characters in your commands. Prepend `echo ` and append `| od -bc` to your commands. Are there any non-ASCII (`man ascii`) characters in your `%` string? `date` seems to think you have 2 `%` strings, so I suspect a separator character.

Comment: @waltinator Owww .. I feel super stupid now .. I made an alias myself: alias date='date -R' in .bash_aliases; gonna remove that right away! Thanks!

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you, and might help others.

Comment: Also `unalias date` in the shells that were started earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Use `type date` to see if `date` is an alias, or comes from a funny directory in `$PATH`.

It turned out that the user had aliased `date` to something suboptimal.